# Parser.pxi problems when pretty printing xml file

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I'm getting some errors when I'm trying to pretty print a xml file. I've looked everywhere and tried installning latest version of lxml but still getting this error.

My script is pretty simple it looks like this.

```
import os
import lxml.etree as etree
from lxml.etree import parse
fname = 'C:\Test_folder\SlutR_20150218.xml'
x = etree.parse(fname)
print etree.tostring(x, pretty_print = True)
```

And the errors I'm getting is following.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File  "C:\Users\a.curcic\Desktop\Övriga_python_script\
Pretty_print_example.py", 
line   5, in <module> x = etree.parse(fname)
File "lxml.etree.pyx", 
line 3301, in lxml.etree.parse      
(src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:72453) 
File "parser.pxi", line 1791, in lxml.etree._parseDocument  
(src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:105915)
File "parser.pxi", line 1817, 
in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:106214)
XMLSyntaxError: 
Extra content at the end of the document, line 2, column 909
```

Comment: Is your XML file well-formed?

Comment: No its writes everything in one line. Thats why I try to prettyprint it